# purpose Of using PackageManager in Android

Tags: android

What is PackageManager?

- What is the purpose of using it ?

What do the following methods describe?:

1. getPackageManager()
2. getApplicationInfo()
3. getPackageName()

Can any one give  detailed description as I could not get complete information in the Android developer guide.

And also one sample program that comprises all the methods.

Answer (score 6):

The Android Package Manager serves a similar function to Linux package managers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager

From [the API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html): "[It's a] Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on the device."

Want to know which apps are installed? [Ask the package manager.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications(int)) And so on.

Comment: Thank you. I got a problem in one Android Application which I am working in which I am getting error when I use PackageManager.

Comment: @Android - then it sounds like you should really be asking a question about the problem you're having, not a totally general "what is package manager" question.

Comment: Problem in Using PackageManager in Android [closed] . This is the problem link

Comment: @Android: I think you're referring to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661367/error-while-using-packagemanager-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

[The Android Developer page for PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) gives a detailed explanation.

Comment: I guess he knows already because he mentions the developer guide in his question ;)

Comment: can we get values of the variables of that package , if we use PackageManager ?