# Problem in Using PackageManager in Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error while using PackageManager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661367/error-while-using-packagemanager-in-android)

I got a problem in one Android Application which I am working in which I am getting error when I use PackageManager. 
  
 The Application is as follows:

## Home.java

package com.main.home 
public class Home extends Activity
{ 
   //onclicking a Button say "send"  
send.onClickListener() 
{  
   public void onClick() { Intent i =new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.main.home","com.main.home.home1");
 startActivity(i); 
 } }

**Home1.java**  
package com.main.home 
import com.andr.resulting.Result ; 
public class Home1 extends Activity  { 
 EditText et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.e1);

 //Clicking on forwardButton in that onClick()
 
public void onClick()
{ 
String s[]={e1.getText().toString(),""};  
//Calling a method in a class Result of another package which is not activity  
 Result.finalfunc(Home1.this,s); 
}
}

## Result.java

package com.andr.resulting   //different package

 import com.andr.other.otherclass

public class Result { 
public static void finalfunc(Activity act,String[] re) { 
**//Here I want to get the details of this particular class's package (com.andr.resulting) using PackageManager**

**I tried like this:**   
otherclass.sendTo("hi","hrll",Result.this.getPackageManager().getApplicationinfo(Result.this.getPacakageName(),0));

I am getting error getPackageManager() doesnot exists in this class file.

 How to solve this Issue.  I will be eagerly waiting for valuable reply 
Thanks in Advance.