# What does "PackageManager" stand for in "PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED"?

Tags: android

I have this problem, I cant understand why this line of code must to be written like this

[image]

What does "PackageManager" stand for?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342436/package-manager-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Package Manager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342436/package-manager-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class PackageManager
```

> Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the
>   application packages that are currently installed on the device.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i dont understand whats the logic, why PERMISSION_GRANTED is linked up with PackageManager as PERMISSION_GRANTED is not a package.

Comment: It's a constant defined in `PackageManager` class. As `PackageManager` is a *Class for retrieving **various kinds of information** related to the application packages*, it also allows querying for permissions granted to a certain package. If you open the source code to `ContextCompat.chekSelfPermission` you'll see that it's just a shortcut to `PackageManager.checkPermission`. So the real question is "why ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission"? And the answer is: the keyword is "self".